# Karlin-Rubin with Beta distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

Suppose $Y$ is one observation from a population with a Beta $(\theta,\ 1)$ pdf. Use the Karlin-Rubin theorem to find a UMP level $\alpha$-test (based on $\mathrm{Y}$) of $H_{0}$ : $\theta\leq 1$ versus $H_{a}:\theta>1.$

I know that the sufficient statistic for this distribution is $\prod Y_i$, so we can say that we will reject $H_0$ if $\prod y_i > k$. I'm not sure where to go from here. I know that I want to specify my $k$ such that $P(\prod y_i>k)=\alpha$ but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y \sim Beta(\theta, 1)$. Then $f_Y(y|\theta) = \theta y^{\theta - 1} \times I(0 < y < 1)$. Now let $Z = -\log Y$. Then by the Jacobian theorem we have that $f_Z(z) = \theta \exp{(-\theta z)} \times I(0 < z < \infty)$. Therefore we can do the following:
$$
- \log \prod_i Y_i = \sum_i - \log Y_i = \sum Z_i \sim Gamma(a, b)
$$

where you can work out $a$ and $b$. This should allow you to calculate the necessary probabilities.